# $onInit not getting called for typescript angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In the below Controller the $onInit() is never called. Please let me know how to ensure $onInit is called. Is there something I need to do bind $onInit for this controller.

Do I need to bind the $onInit to the this object rather than having it as class level function.

```
import * as angular from "angular";
import { IChangePasswordService } from '../../partials/ChangePassword/IChangePasswordService'


declare var module: any;
declare var require: any;
export interface IEmailChangePassword extends ng.IScope {
    initialPasswordChange: Function;
 }

export class EmailChangePasswordController implements ng.IOnInit {

    static $inject = ["$scope", "$mdDialog", "$timeout", "$location", "$state", "ChangePasswordService","common.svcs.modalService"];
    $mdDialog: any;
    $timeout: any;
    state: string = 'getInput';
    $scope: IEmailChangePassword;
    modalService: any;
    ChangePasswordService: IChangePasswordService;
    $location: ng.ILocationService;
    $state: any;

    constructor($scope: IEmailChangePassword, $mdDialog: any, $timeout: any, $location: ng.ILocationService, $state: any, ChangePasswordService: IChangePasswordService, modalService:any) {
        this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
        this.$scope = $scope;
        $scope.initialPasswordChange = this.initialPasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.$timeout = $timeout;
        this.modalService = modalService;
        this.ChangePasswordService = ChangePasswordService;
        this.$location = $location;
        this.$state=$state;
    }


    $onInit(): void {
       console.log("inside On Init");
    }


    public initialPasswordChange(): void {
       ...

    }
}

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.controller("EmailChangePasswordController", EmailChangePasswordController);
}
```

I am using Typescript with angularjs here. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.  If you put a `console.log` statement inside your `constructor`, can you verify that the class is at least being instantiated?

Comment: Yes its getting initialized. I put a break point and it gets there.. :(

Comment: check this article => Look for "Controllers Initialized by ngRoute" https://www.tejusparikh.com/projects/angular_controller_init/index.html#/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$onInit is a hook of component lifecycle in AngularJS.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

It will fire when you'll have this controller assigned to a component, and use 
this component somewhere.

You should have component like:

```
export class EmailChangePasswordComponent {
    controller = EmailChangePasswordController;
    templateUrl = "email-change-password.html";
}
```

You should register it:

```
app.component("emailChangePassword", EmailChangePasswordComponent)
```

You can assign this component to state in a config:

```
$stateProvider.state("stateName", {
    url: "/stateUrl",
    component: "emailChangePassword"
});
```

Or just use in html:

```
<email-change-password></email-change-password>
```

And $onInit will fire when state is initialized, or when component is being renderd.

Difference between **constructor** and **$onInit** is that $onInit will fire only when Element is constructed (you can manipulate DOM element by $element) and when all bindings (inputs to component) are initialized.